# Convert hex to decimal in make script?

Tags: makefile, hex, base-conversion

A **make** script is attempting to set a variable as follows:

```
VER_DEC=$( perl -e "print hex(\"$(VER_HEX)\");" )
```

where `VER_HEX` happens to have a value of `0a`.

Perl seems to think that VER_HEX is zero, implying that the variable isn't set (but it *is*, according to a debug echo in the makefile).

Does make have a simpler way to convert bases?

If so, what version of make is required?

UPDATE: This is a GNU Makefile. The invocation of perl is missing the word `shell` inside the `$( )` as well as potentially having escaping issues with the double-quotes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
VER_DEC=$(shell printf "%d" 0x$(VER_HEX))
```

if you're talking about `Makefile`. Because your doesn't look like `Makefile` to me, more like shell. (I think `$(shell )` is GNU extension, but most of time you can safely replace it with backticks).